# Ejecutar comando cli en web PHP

Tags: php, cli

O tengo un problema y quiero ver si tiene una solución eficaz.

Estoy armando un sistema de stream instagram a base de uno creado desde github.

dejo repositorio del [autor](https://github.com/JRoy/InstagramLive-PHP) 
Lo que quiero es que en vez de abrir una consola y escribir los comandos

```sh
php update.php
```

o

```sh
php goLive.php
```

Se pueda ingresar desde la web automaticamente, osea cuando ingreso al localhost/goLive.php sale el siguiente error: This script may not be run on a website!

Entonces ya he probado con el codigo

```php
<?php
$output = shell_exec("php -n -s goLive.php");
echo "$output";
?>
```

Pero aún así no hay resultado solo muestra la pagina en blanco.

Comment: Pero , ¿ `goLive.php` está en el mismo servidor de la web que refieres? ¿Por qué no accedes a él vía URL: `dominio.com/goLive.php`?  ¿O bien vía `include`?

Comment: Te explico, goLive.php esta en la misma web/servidor, Has leido bien que dice "This script may not be run on a website!", por favor antes de responder leer bien el tema. Gracias por tu ayuda. y no lo necesito via include, ya que debe correr en la web.

Comment: Lo anterior no es una respuesta, sino un comentario, tratando de entender mejor tu contexto. No entiendo por qué si el archivo está en el mismo servidor no lo incluyes sin más ¿ ? Ten en cuenta que PHP no se ejecuta nunca del lado del cliente (el que abre una URL cualquiera) sino del lado del servidor. Por eso motivo no entiendo para nada el modo en que intentas proceder en este caso.